# Coloring rows based on comparison between two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an Excel macro that deletes a couple of columns, adjusts the sizing and format of some other columns and then needs to color rows depending on the comparison of two dates in columns `G` and `H`. Rule needs to be if dates mentioned in `G` is equal or later then the date in H then that row needs to get a back ground color green, if the dates is earlier within 4 weeks then it needs to be colored yellow and anything earlier then 4 weeks should be colored red.

I've tried to achieve this with the following code, sadly I'm not that experienced with Excel Macro's so if anyone has any help I would be grateful:

```
Set DelIndi = Range("H:H")
For Each Cell In DelIndi
    Select Case Cell.Value

        Case Is > Range("G:G").Value
            Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        Case Is < Range("G:G").Value
            Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5

        Case Is = "9999999"
            Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        'Case Else
            'Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    End Select

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting isn't super pretty here, but this will work

```
Sub colorCells()

For i = x To y
    If (Range("G" & i).Value >= Range("H" & i).Value) Then
        Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.Color = 5287936
    Else

        If (Range("G" & i).Value >= (Range("h" & i).Value - 28)) Then
            Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.Color = 65535
        Else
            Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.Color = 255
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Where it says `For i = x to y`, change x to the first row you want to color and y to the last row you want to color. Note that any blank rows will be colored yellow.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for the advice and help, it's very appreciated.

I've tried your solution (which on its own works perfectly) with a change where I have tried to select a range for i as I don't know how many rows there will be each time I run the script. Sadly I'm unable to make the right adjustments, do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: -------
For Each i In ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Cells
        If (Range("G" & i).Value >= Range("H" & i).Value) Then
            Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.Color = 5287936
        Else

            If (Range("G" & i).Value >= (Range("h" & i).Value - 28)) Then
                Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.Color = 65535
            Else
                Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Interior.Color = 255
            End If
        End If
    Next i
---------

Comment: I've fixed the selection part at the start by doing the following:

'    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim y As Integer

    Set myRange = Range("A:A")
    y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
    For i = 2 To y'

Thanks for the help, it's all working great now :D